# Full switch from windows to ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, backup

Recently I partitioned my hard drive an allocated 60 GB of space to an Ubuntu dual-boot. However, I realized I've spent the majority of my time on Ubuntu and would like to replace windows with Ubuntu full-time. How would I go about doing this (would I need to backup? How would I merge my Windows partition with my Ubuntu partition?)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Please boot the Ubuntu LiveDVD and take the "try Ubuntu" option, go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `sudo gparted --list`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question.